# tuned-adm set how to set default power profile

Tags: tuned

using RHEL/CentOS 7.9 I know how to do `tuned-adm profile   latency-performance`

However after reboot it is back to `throughput-performance`.

How, or where, does tuned specify the default power profile and what is the correct way to modify things such that after reboot the power profile is always what I want it to be?

Comment: The [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/index#setting-a-tuned-profile_getting-started-with-tuned) mentions a reboot command as part of the process. After running `tuned-adm profile latency-performance`, can you run `tuned-adm active` and confirm that the profile is active? I'm asking because the `tuned-adm` command just exits if you give it an invalid profile name.

Comment: What is the output of `tuned-adm active` before a reboot, and what do the contents of `/var/log/tuned/tuned.log` say after a reboot?